# Google Books App Script for grabbing book covers

Tags: google-sheets

I´m fairly new to writing Google App Scripts and wanted to use it for my book tracker. The idea is that the app script should grab the book cover from google books based from its unique ISBN. The problem is, my code kinda stopped working and I dont know why. The script just gives out "there is no cover for that ISBN, but I tried it with ISBNs directly taken from the google Books page.

help is much appreciated.

See code below

```
function insertBookCover() {
  var sheetName = 'Books';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  if (sheet && sheet.getSheetName() === sheetName) {
    var isbnColumn = 4;
    var coverColumn = 5;
    var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var cellColumn = activeCell.getColumn();

    if (cellColumn === isbnColumn) {
      var isbn = activeCell.getValue();
      var imageUrl = getBookCoverUrl(isbn);

      if (imageUrl) {
        if (sheet.getMaxColumns() <= coverColumn) {
          sheet.insertColumnAfter(isbnColumn);
        }

        var imageUrlBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setFormula('=image("' + imageUrl + '")');
      } else {
        Logger.log('Kein Bild gefunden für ISBN: ' + isbn);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('Funktion sollte in Spalte ' + isbnColumn + ' aufgerufen werden.');
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('Tabellenblatt ' + sheetName + ' nicht gefunden oder nicht aktiv.');
  }
}


function getBookCoverUrl(isbn) {
  var apiKey = '"my API Key!';
  var apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:' + isbn + '&key=' + apiKey + '&country=DE';

  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, { 'muteHttpExceptions': true });
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    if (data.totalItems > 0) {
      return data.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Fehler beim Abrufen der Buchinformationen: ' + e);
  }

  return null;
}
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  insertBookCover();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Just incase you are good to go with a formula-based approach:*

```js
=image(concatenate("https://images.isbndb.com/covers/",
              left(right(A2,4),2),"/",right(A2,2),"/",A2,".jpg"))
```

[image]